# C# - Fill Spinner with an array from resource file

Tags: c#, xamarin, spinner

(I am struggling with a simple problem I think!?

In my android app I made a spinner that will be filled with 2 values: **On** and **Off**. So I created a file called **Arrays.xml** in Resources/values/

Now I thought that I need something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
Spinner ActionSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.ActionSpinner);
ActionSpinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(ActionSpinner_ItemSelected);
var ActionSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.action_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
ActionSpinnerAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
ActionSpinner.Adapter = ActionSpinnerAdapter;
```

The spinner stays empty and I don't know what to do... Someone else asked this question too on this site, but this awnser doesn't seem to work for me. This was his awnser:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code you had looks good, so the issue must be somewhere else, perhaps in your string-array definition. Please show all relevant files, including the Arrays.xml and the Layout file that ActionSpinner item is in. It might help to look over this verified working sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Import a string-array from resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860697/how-do-i-import-a-string-array-from-resources)