# How do I Import a string-array from resources?

Tags: c#, xamarin, spinner

I have a problem with importing a string-array!

When I try the code below, The Spinners stay empty and don't load the array string values. This is my code I use:

```
//Fill CoinSpinner
Spinner CoinSpinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.CoinSpinner);
CoinSpinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>(CoinSpinner_ItemSelected);
ArrayAdapter<String> CoinSpinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Resource.Array.coin_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
//ArrayAdapter CoinSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(this, Resource.Array.coin_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
CoinSpinnerAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
CoinSpinner.Adapter = CoinSpinnerAdapter;
```

I want to import a string-array from Resources/values/String.xml.... What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
This is the String.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">TestApp</string>
    <string name="coins_prompt">Coin:</string>
    <string-array name="coin_array">
        <item>EUR</item>
        <item>USD</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The name doesn't exist in the current context - How to resolve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33009273/the-name-doesnt-exist-in-the-current-context-how-to-resolve)

Comment: Xamarin/C# uses `Resource.xxx.xxx` vs. the Java `R.xxx.xxx`

Comment: Can you all look at the updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`R.array.coin_array` is for pure native Android development where `R` is the resource class that has all of the resource IDs for all of your resources. In Xamarin.Android `R` becomes `Resource`, so try `Resource.Array.coin_array` instead.

EDIT:

Working code sample to populate a spinner with a string-array in resources:

Layout AXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
   <Button android:id="@+id/myButton" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:text="@string/hello" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView" 
              android:layout_width="match_parent" 
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="@string/on_off" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner"
             android:layout_width="match_parent" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:prompt="@string/on_off"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <string name="hello">Hello World, Click Me!</string>
   <string name="app_name">SpinnerArray</string>
   <string name="on_off">On or Off</string>
   <string-array name="spinnerArray">
      <item>On</item>
      <item>Off</item>
   </string-array>
</resources>
```

C# code:

```
Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
spinner.ItemSelected += new EventHandler<AdapterView.ItemSelectedEventArgs>
        (spinner_ItemSelected);
var spinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource
        (this, Resource.Array.spinnerArray, 
         Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
spinnerAdapter.SetDropDownViewResource 
        (Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
spinner.Adapter = spinnerAdapter;
```

I have verified that the above works to populate a spinner from a string-array in resources.

Comment: It looks like you asked three questions about this one issue. This one, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53859338/c-sharp-fill-spinner-with-an-array-from-resource-file and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871290/fill-spinner-with-list . But in the end you just have to follow this sample to answer all  three questions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/spinner